# Parfor in MATLAB Problem

Tags: matlab

Why can't I use the `parfor` in this piece of code?

```
parfor i=1:r

    for j=1:N/r

        xr(j + (N/r) * (i-1)) = x(i + r * (j-1));

    end

end
```

This is the error:

> Error: The variable xr in a parfor cannot be classified.
>    See Parallel for Loops in MATLAB, "Overview".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The issue here is that of improper indexing of the sliced array. `parfor` loops are run **asynchronously**, meaning the order in which each iteration is executed is random. From the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/distcomp/brb2x2l-1.html#brb2x57):

> MATLAB workers evaluate iterations in no particular order, and independently of each other. Because each iteration is independent, there is no guarantee that the iterations are synchronized in any way, nor is there any need for this.

You can easily verify the above statement by typing the following in the command line:

```
parfor i=1:100
    i
end
```

You'll see that the ordering is arbitrary. Hence if you split a parallel job between different workers, one worker has no way of telling if a different iteration has finished or not. Hence, your variable indexing *cannot* depend on past/future values of the iterator.

Let me demonstrate this with a simple example. Consider the Fibonacci series `1,1,2,3,5,8,...`. You can generate the first 10 terms of the series easily (in a naïve `for` loop) as:

```
f=zeros(1,10);
f(1:2)=1;
for i=3:10
    f(i)=f(i-1)+f(i-2);
end
```

Now let's do the same with a `parfor` loop.

```
f=zeros(1,10);
f(1:2)=1;
parfor i=3:10
    f(i)=f(i-1)+f(i-2);
end
```

> ??? Error: The variable f in a parfor cannot be classified.
>    See Parallel for Loops in MATLAB, "Overview"

But why does this give an error?

I've shown that iterations are executed in an arbitrary order. So let's say that a worker gets the loop index `i=7` and the expression `f(i)=f(i-1)+f(i-2);`. It is now supposed to execute the expression and return the results to the master node. Now has iteration `i=6` finished? Is the value stored in `f(6)` reliable? What about `f(5)`? Do you see what I'm getting at? Supposing `f(5)` and `f(6)` are not done, then you'll incorrectly calculate that the 7th term in the Fibonnaci series is 0!

Since MATLAB has no way of telling if your calculation can be guaranteed to run *correctly* and reproduce the *same* result each time, such ambiguous assignments are explicitly disallowed.

Comment: It is still giving me the error:  Error: The variable xr in a parfor cannot be classified.
 See Parallel for Loops in MATLAB, "Overview".

Error in ==> Code1 at 36
parfor i=1:r

Comment: I was looking at: http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/distcomp/brdqtjj-1.html       and could not figure out why xr cannot be classified

Comment: @user123668 I just noticed an error in your code. What you're doing is not possible with `parfor`

Comment: Can you explain it more in detail? Thansk for your help! I really need to know why this algorithm cannot be parallelized.

Comment: @user123668 Sure, give me some time while I write it up.

Comment: @user123668 That should have been `x(i-1)=x(i)` like in your example. Please see my current edit, where I've tried to explain what happens under the hood and why it doesn't work.