# parfor is much slower than for when matlabpool is not lauched

Tags: matlab

in matlab' s document, it is said that if matlabpool is not launched, then parfor will be interpreted as for

this implies that they are as efficient as each other

however, in my code below, i find that parfor is 6 times slower than for.

===================================

```
  clear all; close all; clc; tic 

  Nx=10;   Ny=10; 
   plist=0.05:0.05:0.95; 
  linked_list=zeros(1,length(plist)); 

 num_sample=20000; 
 % matlabpool open 3 
parfor sss=1:length(plist) 
sss 
p=plist(sss); 

numlink=0; 
for s10=1:num_sample 
    pattern=(rand(Ny,Nx)<p); 
    pattern2=zeros(Ny,Nx); 

    new=zeros(2,10000); 
    new2=zeros(2,10000); 
    num_new=0; 
    num_new2=0; 

    flag=0; 
    found=0; 
    s=0; 
    while (found==0)&&(s<Nx) 
        s=s+1; 
        if (pattern(1,s)==1)&&(pattern2(1,s)==0); 
            flag=flag+1; 

            pattern2(1,s)=flag; 

            num_new=1; 
            new(1,1)=s; 
            new(2,1)=1; 
            num_new2=0; 

            while num_new>0 
                num_new2=0; 
                for s1=1:num_new 
                    x=new(1,s1); 
                    y=new(2,s1); 
                    if (x-1>0)&&(pattern(y,x-1)==1)&&(pattern2(y,x-1)~=flag) 
                        num_new2=num_new2+1; 
                        new2(1,num_new2)=x-1; 
                        new2(2,num_new2)=y; 
                        pattern2(y,x-1)=flag; 
                    end 
                    if (x+1<=Nx)&&(pattern(y,x+1)==1)&&(pattern2(y,x+1)~=flag) 
                        num_new2=num_new2+1; 
                        new2(1,num_new2)=x+1; 
                        new2(2,num_new2)=y; 
                        pattern2(y,x+1)=flag; 
                    end 
                    if (y-1>0)&&(pattern(y-1,x)==1)&&(pattern2(y-1,x)~=flag) 
                        num_new2=num_new2+1; 
                        new2(1,num_new2)=x; 
                        new2(2,num_new2)=y-1; 
                        pattern2(y-1,x)=flag; 
                    end 
                    if (y+1<=Ny)&&(pattern(y+1,x)==1)&&(pattern2(y+1,x)~=flag) 
                        num_new2=num_new2+1; 
                        new2(1,num_new2)=x; 
                        new2(2,num_new2)=y+1; 
                        pattern2(y+1,x)=flag; 
                    end 
                end 

                num_new=num_new2; 
                new(:,1:num_new)=new2(:,1:num_new); 

                if max(new(2,1:num_new))==Ny 
                    found=1; 
                    break; 
                end 
            end 
        end 
    end 
    numlink=numlink+found; 
 end 
 linked_list(sss)=numlink/num_sample; 
 end 


  plot(plist,linked_list,'*') 

  toc
```

Comment: I had thought that the culprit might have been parfor using single-threaded versions in the client (as is the case in the labs), but with no labs open, the client does indeed use the multi-threaded versions. This has often been the culprit for me when parfor with many labs speed-up has not been much (and of course the communication overhead issues).

Answer (score 4):

If you do not reserve a pool of workers using `matlabpool`, then `parfor` merely *behaves* like a `for` loop because it executes the loop on the client *serially* instead of in parallel. **However, it is not the same as a `for` loop**. Here's a simple example to illustrate (run without opening a pool):

#### Parfor loop:

```
parfor i=0:9
    fprintf('%u',i)
end

OUTPUT --> 9876543210
```

#### For loop:

```
for i=0:9   
    fprintf('%u',i)
end
OUTPUT --> 0123456789
```

You can readily see that the order of execution is different that what I specified in `parfor`.

You're correct that `parfor` is significantly slower than `for` (I get ~6 times slower too) and this is because `parfor` needs to make additional checks for proper array slicing, indexing, etc., as [discussed in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7369037/parfor-in-matlab-problem/7369565#7369565) and these will invariably slow you down.